# Lualatex Precompile Preamble Stops Randomly

Tags: luatex, preamble

to speed up the compilation of my tex-file I came across the idea of precompiling the preamble following this explaination: https://web.archive.org/web/20160912114941/http://www.howtotex.com:80/tips-tricks/faster-latex-part-iv-use-a-precompiled-preamble/

I am using lualatex as I am including some luacode, use quiet a lot of packages and some makros.

Now when I run:

```
lualatex -ini -jobname="preamble" --halt-on-error --shell-escape -file-line-error "&lualatex" mylatexformat.ltx Preamble.tex
```

the compiling process just stops randomly without any error at some part within the preamble-file:
[image]

Is there a way to log the error properly or does somebody have any of the latest suggestion/ experience with precompiling a preamble with lualatex in 2024?

I am using MX Linux (Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)), Tex Live 2022/Debian & LuaHBTex 1.15.0

Thanks in advance!

Comment: as you can not save lua state in the format, making a custom lualatex format is quite tricky and usually requires specific changes to the lua call in any packages loaded so you would need to show a complete small document (and the answer may be that you can not pre-load the packages you are using)

Comment: the error is never "random" you have the  `*` prompt which means that tex has read to the end of the file without seeing a command to stop so it is now waiting for more input from the terminal.

Comment: Ok thx @DavidCarlisle for your comments. I forgot /begin{document} at the end of Preamble.tex. Now I got the preamble.fmt file mentioned in tutorial from my question. 
I tried including it within the Maindocument.tex file in the first line like: 

%&preamble
\begin{document}

Now it seems as if the preamble-code is not included in the Maindocument.tex 

Do you or sb. maybe know if this is still the correct approach of including the precompiled preamble within a tex-file?

Comment: as I said any package using lua or loading fonts can't be preloaded without modification with luatex so with no example shown impossible really to help